# Confirmar correo API net core

Tags: email, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

tengo una API REST con .net Core que la consumo con VUEJS pero me he estancado en una parte, resulta que ya he hecho el tema de autenticación con jwt, crea usuarios nuevos y todo el tema, pero necesito que el usuario al registrarse reciba un mail de confirmación, no he encontrado documentación de cómo hacerlo con una API ya que este tipo de proyecto en visual studio no genera el modelo de cuentas ni el accountcontroller por lo que toca hacerlo todo desde cero, los ejemplos que he encontrado son con MVC 5 y la verdad no los he entendido muy bien, ps eso como me pueden ayudar?
Enviar correo de confirmación cuando un nuevo usuario se registra

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso debes enviarle un mail al usuario con un link a tu web de VUE para que muestre un mensaje de cuenta de usuario ya activa mientras tanto se manda un request a un API con el código de activación (que debe estar en el link enviado por mail) para que el Identity realice la activación.

Por una lado, debes activar la activación del usuario por mail desde el Identity, la docu oficial indica como hacerlo https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

En ese link indica que se utiliza [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/?opt=ns) para enviar los mails, es muy bueno y fácil de utilizarlo.

Una opción a SendGrid es utilizar el SMPT de alguna cuenta de email (gmail por ejemplo). Aquí detallan como realizarlo https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/08/20/sending-email-net-core-2-0/ .